# How can we use Julia with in Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab?

Tags: amazon-web-services, julia, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

It is possible to [run Julia in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb), and that's pretty helpful when you need to create computing power demanding algorithms from scratch, without going into the hell of Python optimization and having a readable Matlab-like syntax to make the maths clearer.

Is there also a way to use Julia with Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As for the use of Julia in aws SageMaker the is an step-by-step guide here:
https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/julia-on-sagemaker.pdf?did=wp_card&trk=wp_card

I'm experiencing some problems using Julia 1.7.2 in SageMaker and currently working with Julia 1.1.1 without any problem.